# Maintaining weighted average proportions in Excel when there is null data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, pivot-table

I am not sure how to recalculate weights in Excel, preferably in a PivotTable, when there is null data (i.e., survey administrators didn't write anything).

Please refer to [this workbook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1szMvr1BqbC3LrrudC19ius24WR-JzBGX/view?usp=sharing), where I have built an example. The info below is in there too.

I have created weighted averages, using assigned weights that work out to a desired proportion (see "Weight" sheet). But because I have null data that I have set to be excluded, the WeightingFactors are no longer accurate because those are the WeightingFactors for a full dataset without nulls.

The WeightingFactors should change, because the sum of the Weights have changed due to data being excluded, right? I want the Weights and WeightingFactors to change dynamically depending on what I filter for in the PivotTable, since in my actual data, I have multiple Households with null data in various Room_Category entries. I want the Weights and WeightingFactors to change dynamically such that the weights for the entries I do have data for work out to the same desired proportions from the "Weight" sheet.

1) How do I recalculate those Weights so that they match my desired proportions?
2) How do I recalculate those Weights dynamically in a PivotTable?

This is my first time using a forum to ask questions, sorry for any poor etiquette!

Comment: I believe something like `SUMPRODUCT(A2:A10,B2:B10)/SUM(A2:A10)` should give you what you want (assumes the weights are in `A2:A10` and the data is in `B2:B10`)

Comment: Thank you, I think that makes sense. But I can't use `SUMPRODUCT` if there are null values, so I set the nulls equal to 0. Every category in my data has varying amounts of "null" values though, so when there are a lot of "null"s (a.k.a., a surveyor left many questions blank), then there are a lot of 0s, and so the overall weighted average drops drastically. Maybe this result is just inevitable? Maybe I should just get better surveyors?

Comment: It may be best to provide sample data and the expected result as well as what you've tried so far and the results you get and why they are incorrect